# Prove that the following formula is a contradiction ((¬p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q)) ∧ (p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove the following formula is a contradiction and would love some help:

```
((¬p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q)) ∧ (p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p)
```

I tried simplifying `(¬p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q)` with the distributive law but it does not work since the nots get in the way. I understand logically how this statement is a contradiction, but do not know how to legally prove it with predicate logic.

An example of a proof I am looking for is like this:

```
Prove φ ∶= p ∧ (p ⇒ q) ⇒ q is a tautology 

p ∧ (p ⇒ q) ⇒ q 
    ≡ p ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ⇒ q (using Implication as OR)
    ≡ ((p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (p ∧ q)) ⇒ q (using Distributivity)
    ≡ (false ∨ (p ∧ q)) ⇒ q (using Operation with Negation)
    ≡ (p ∧ q) ⇒ q (using Operation with false)
    ≡ true
```

[Source: this online textbook](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeepc/Courses/W20/lecs/lec2+3.pdf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Easiest way of proving it is a contradiction is with a truth table.

Comment: The left hand side of the conjunction says that a counter-example must exist for at least one of the propositions in the right side of the conjunction. Since both implications and at least one of the counter-examples must be true, the whole thing is impossible.

Comment: $((¬p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q))$ is equivalent to `p XOR q` or $p \ne q$.  $(p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p)$ is equivalent to `p XNOR q` or $p = q$.  ANDing two opposite things gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

When is $p\to q$ false? The answer is when we can find an instance where $p$ is true and $q$ is false,i.e. $p\land\lnot q\iff\lnot (p\to q)$

Therefore, we can translate your proposition to $$(\lnot(q\to p)\lor\lnot (p\to q))\land ((p\to q)\land(q\to p))$$

Can you see why this is always false?